# Missing package `udunits2` on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

I'd like to use `gganimate`, but it requires the package `sf`.

I tried to install, but I get this error.

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpEpee0m/R.INSTALL282e663ea13f/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’
* removing ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/units’
```

I'm on CentOS hosted on EC2 and I'm unable to install `libudunits2.so`.

I've tried

```
sudo yum install udunits2-dev
sudo yum install udunits2-devel
sudo yum install udunits2
sudo yum install libcairo2-devel libjpeg8-devel libpango1.0-devel libgif-devel build-essential g++
sudo yum install libcairo2-dev libjpeg8-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++
```

For each of those commands, I get back `No package available`

Answer (score 1):

The correct package name is `udunits2-devel` and as the output you posted indicates, it is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

Before you can install this package, you need to enable EPEL on your system. Do this by installing the `epel-release` RPM:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

After it is installed, then you can install `udunits2-devel`.

Comment: When I run the command, I get `Package epel-release-6-8.9.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version` and when I run `sudo yum install udunits2-devel` afterwards I get `No package udunits2-devel available.`

Comment: @goollan You are not using CentOS, but Amazon Linux. You cannot use EPEL or udunits2 at all. EPEL is not compatible with Amazon Linux, and Amazon Linux is not compatible with CentOS. Get rid of Amazon Linux and use CentOS instead.

Comment: FWIW, I used the instructions here and set EPEL to enabled and successfully installed the package https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Comment: @goollan OK, but you should still get rid of Amazon Linux. It really is not 100% compatible and your system will mysteriously break one day when they change something.